# How can I use regex in Python to read between HTML tags from the bottom of the file?

Tags: python, html, regex, parsing, response

I have a HTML response, and I need to get the data between the last `<title>` tags on the page, is there a way I can do this with regex in Python or use another tool in Python?

eg.

```
<title>abc
</title>

<title>def
</title>
```

Should return def.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `<title>\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*</title>` as your regex (strips away leading and trailing whitespace from the title) with `findall` and take the last occurrence:

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RusLwD/2/)

```
import re

text = """abc
<title>abc
</title>
def
ghi
<title>def
</title>
jkl
"""

tags = re.findall(r'<title>\s*([\s\S]+?)\s*</title>', text)
print(tags[-1]) # the last one
```

Prints:

```
def
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use regex to parse HTML as most of the times is inefficient and hard to read. Regex should be the last resort if you don't have any other options. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) for more info.

Thankfully there are plenty of HTML parsers for Python like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

With BeautifulSoup you can get the last title tag with this:

```
last_title = soup.find_all('title')[-1].text.replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: But you should probably, in this case, strip the resulting text of that nasty trailing newline.

Comment: @Booboo You are right. I didn't notice that. I just edited my code, thanks for the heads up.